# Why don't CMS databases use Foreign Keys?

Tags: mysql, database, content-management-system, foreign-keys, relational-database

Why do CMS databases (e.g. WP and PRESTASHOP) not use foreign keys on their tables? I thought tables should have foreign keys to prevent orphan rows.

Comment: that is mostly historical thing I guess, a lot of code and queries is there for a long time. Nobody want to refactor a huge project for nothing (nobody really care about orphan rows :-) ). WP and other cms mostly used in small projects, when they become bigger dovelopers can redesign some queries if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpted from a post (apparently by WP staff) at
[wordpress.org
WordPress › Support » Plugins and Hacks » Hacks](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/integrity-constraints)

> The problem with MySQL is that only a few installations default to innodb. Most use MyISAM tables because they are more "beginner friendly".
>
> Because of this WordPress, and pretty much every other PHP-based CMS that I've seen out there, has to think that it will be using the lowest common denominator, so MyISAM tables with no references are required so it can be as universal as possible.
>
> I will add that the WP system has been set up to use the PHP code to enforce the integrity where it can. That's why it's always best to use the built-in WordPress functions rather then trying to roll your own.

Only the MySQL InnoDB storage engine enforces foreign key declaration. But they are treated as comments with the MyISAM storage engine, so I don't know why they weren't declared anyway.

Posts by a "Custom Prestashop Software Solutions and Shared and Dedicated Virtual hosting services" member at
[prestashop.com Forum > Technical Forum > Adapting my PrestaShop > Development](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/424387-mysql-error-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/)

> Because it is only supported when using InnoDB, and not everyone uses that.
>
> And btw, backwards compatibility and thorough testing is not something that Prestashop is famous for.